# does nest-asyncio runs coroutins on separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, python-asyncio, tornado, nest-asyncio

We're using tornadoweb which already runs an event loop single-threaded, and we want to use asyncio.run to run other coroutines, but it show error 'Event loop already running', found this library nest-asyncio that allows event loop to be nested, sorry not expert on threading or event loop, does nest-asyncio runs coroutines on separated thread?or no connection on threading?

Answer (score 0):

If the event loop is already running, you can't call `asyncio.run`.

You have a few options:

**1. Tornado's [`IOLoop.add_callback`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback)**:

This will run the coroutine in the background (that means you won't be able to get it's result).

```py
from tornado import ioloop

loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current() # get the current running event loop

loop.add_callback(coro_func) # coro_func is the coroutine you want to run
```

**2. Use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)**:

This will also allow you to get the coroutine's result.

Comment: Using nest-asyncio..i was able to run asyncio.run since it allows nested event loop...question is..is it running on the same thread?

Comment: @user18960204 It will be a good idea to ask this directly to the project author. Perhaps in github issues